# How To Unpack SPARQL Resultset Into Triples in DBpedia Query

Tags: sparql, resultset, dbpedia

I have a DBpedia query I'm using on [Virtuoso](https://dbpedia.org/sparql/) like this:

```
SELECT ?state ?stateLabel ?population 
WHERE {
     ?state rdf:type dbo:AdministrativeRegion ;
            rdfs:label ?stateLabel ;
            dbo:country dbr:India ;
            dbo:populationTotal ?population.
     FILTER (lang(?stateLabel) = "en")}
ORDER BY ?stateLabel
```

The actual query is much longer and I've omitted the prefixes. I want to get triples, for example:

```
dbr:Dharwad_district dbo:populationTotal 1847023
```

that I can import into an OWL ontology. The results I get are in a results set. I can't figure out how to extract the triples from the result set data structure. For example, in Turtle, the first lines of the results are:

```
@prefix res: <http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
_:_ a res:ResultSet .
_:_ res:resultVariable "state" , "stateLabel" , "abs" , "latitude" , "longitude" , "population" , "city" , "cityLabel" .
@prefix dbr:    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> .
@prefix xsd:    <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
_:_ res:solution [
      res:binding [ res:variable "state" ; res:value dbr:Aalo ] ;
      res:binding [ res:variable "stateLabel" ; res:value "Aalo"@en ] ;...
```

Comment: Are you interested in proper RDF triples? If so, you need a `CONSTRUCT` query instead of a `SELECT` query. Like `CONSTRUCT {?state rdf:type dbo:AdministrativeRegion ;
            rdfs:label ?stateLabel ;
            dbo:country dbr:India ;
            dbo:populationTotal ?population   } WHERE {
     ?state rdf:type dbo:AdministrativeRegion ;
            rdfs:label ?stateLabel ;
            dbo:country dbr:India ;
            dbo:populationTotal ?population.
     FILTER (lang(?stateLabel) = "en")}`

Comment: This would return proper RDF. Note, for a tool like Protege, you would also need the OWL ontology schema triples such that the OWL parser knows the type of the entities, at least for the properties. Otherwise, usually the parser handles those as annotation properties because it's just RDF data here which hasn't strict types on properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative (to extracting the relevant triples from the `res:ResultSet`) could be to use a SPARQL [`CONSTRUCT`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#construct) query.

You can keep the `WHERE` clause, and instead of the `SELECT` clause, you add a `CONSTRUCT` clause which describes the triples you want to produce.

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?state dbo:populationTotal ?population .
} 
WHERE {
  ?state 
    rdf:type dbo:AdministrativeRegion ;
    rdfs:label ?stateLabel ;
    dbo:country dbr:India ;
    dbo:populationTotal ?population .
  FILTER (lang(?stateLabel) = "en")
}
ORDER BY ?stateLabel
```